# When kafka consumer poll return null records?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

As show as below, my code is a high level consumer fetch a topic with 32 partitions in kafka server, I'm confused that why sometimes I get a empty return from consumer.poll(). 
I have tried to increase poll timeout, and then when I increase timeout to 1000, then each poll has return data while I set timeout to 10 or 0, then I see a lot of empty return.

Can anyone tell me how to set a correct timeout ?

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka-01:9098")
    props.put("group.id", "kch1")
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true")
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

    //props.put("max.poll.records", "1000")
    val consumers = new Array[KafkaConsumer[String, String]](16)
    for(i <- 0 to 15) {
      consumers(i) = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
      consumers(i).subscribe(util.Arrays.asList("veh321"))
    }
    var cnt = 0
    var cacheIterator: Iterator[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = null
    for(i <- 0 to 15) {
      new Thread(new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          var finish = false
          while(!finish) {
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            cacheIterator = consumers(i).poll(100).iterator()
            val end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            if (end > 10 ) {
              println(s"${Thread.currentThread().getId} + Duration is ${end}， ${cacheIterator.hasNext} ${cacheIterator.size}")
            }
          }
        }
      }).start()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java consumer employs Linux's epoll as the underlying implementation scheme by invoking java.nio.channels.Selector.select(timeout). It is very likely to return nothing if you only give it 100 ms to try how many SelectionKeys are ready during that short time interval.

Besides, during the same 100 ms, consumer will do some other jobs including polling coordinator status, so the real time interval for record polling is obviously less than 100ms which makes harder to retrieve some really useful things.

Comment: so if I set a poll time out to 1000ms, I can see all the poll have data return, some of them cost about 200ms, while others cost just a few milliseconds, so what happens when poll cost need hundreds of seconds ? Are there any parameters to turning this ?

Comment: Many underlying operations need to be done before retrieving records, such as obtaining metadata, managing connections and groups etc. You could tune `max.poll.records` to control the message count for single round of poll if you are using Java consumer.

Comment: Thanks for you help, so if I want a big throughput, I can set a big poll.records and a big poll timeout so that decrease the times of poll , am i right ?

Comment: Frankly to say, I do not agree. There is no such tuning between TPS and configs applicable everywhere. A thorough performance testing is needed.